# Continue editing cell of TableView

Tags: javafx

I have such code:

```
columnNumber.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Record>forTableColumn());
columnNumber.setOnEditCommit(
    (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Record, String> t) -> {
        ((Record) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
        ).setNumber(t.getNewValue());
    });
```

It is necessary that after pressing the Enter button and in case of inputting non-number, would be displayed a message, and then editing is not canceled, but entering a value would continue.. Like that:

```
columnNumber.setOnEditCommit(
    (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Record, String> t) -> {
        if(!NumberUtils.isNumber(t.getNewValue())){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error");
            alert.setContentText("Please enter the number");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }else {
            ((Record) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
            ).setNumber(t.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```

But I can't figure out how to make the continue entering.

Comment: that's not supported - the moment the edit handler is notified, the edit is terminated: the handler can accept or reject the edit, but not re-enter the editing state. You might consider to implement a custom editing cell with a TextFormatter that doesn't allow invalid input. Or else go to great length to start editing again ... tricky, because editing is not a loved child ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you so much for your reply!